# Asp.net Application_End Timeout

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool, application-end

In Asp.Net when an application pool stops, invokes the application_end event.
In this event i execute some operations who must be completed before the application shutdown.
These operations are synchronously but sometimes application stops without all operation completed, but there are no errors.
I think there is a timeout at application pool level or at application_end event level.. but i haven't found nothing in documentation about this timeout.

Answer (score 1):

This timeout is configurable by app pool ([iis.net](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel)). It's `shutdownTimeLimit`, or `Shutdown Time Limit (seconds)` in the UI (advanced app pool settings).